# F1 visa DS 160: Contact person in home country

Tags: usa, student-visa

I'm a student from China who is attending a PhD program in the US. I got my BS from the US, but in the DS 160 form, two additional points of contact from China are required. However, since I did my undergrad in the US, the points of contact to confirm my graduate study are all in the US and I don't know anyone who can confirm in China other than my parents. Then can I put someone in the US for that section of the form? If not, then can I put my high school teachers, who don't even know which grad school I'm attending?

Comment: Why do you think the points of contact in China are supposed to be able to confirm your graduate study? That doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: That's just part of the form. It said two additional points of contact in your country of residence.

Answer (score 1):

As part of the section for those who are either a student or exchange visitor, you are asked for the name, address, phone, and email of two individuals in your home country. These cannot be family members or other relatives, but should be those whom you trust to vouch for you personally. They would not be asked details of your US studies, and educators from your high school years would be good choices. When you include such persons, it would be a courtesy to let them know you've listed them, however unlikely it might be that they would be contacted.